# How to match an array's structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays which will always have the same number of elements within them.

```
var array1 = [["John","Barry","Anne"],["Greg"],["Tom"],["Roy","Rye"]]
var array2 = ["Banana","Orange","Apple","Grape","Pineapple","Raspberry","Pear"]
```

I want `array2` to have the same array structure as `array1`, so it should look like:

```
var newArray = [["Banana","Orange","Apple"],["Grape"],["Pineapple"],["Raspberry","Pear"]]
```

I have tried using the `length` of `array1` to firstly create a `new array` of the right `length` and then looping over that `array` to create the `nested arrays` with the right `length`. Then using a `for loop`, pushing `array2's element` to this `new array` but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

```
  var array = new Array(array1.length)
  var arrayLength = array1.map(x => x.length)

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array(arrayLength[i]);
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array[k].length; j++) {
      array[0][k].push(array2[j])
    }
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you ask a question, then please use a valid example. The first version had numbers in `array1` that could be used as "index" to get the elements from `array2`. Your edit now changed that completely by replacing the numbers in `array1` into strings that have no relations at all with `array2`. Both answers are now invalid and have to be deleted or adapted.

Comment: I apologise for not being clearer in my initial post. The example for array1 was the simply the most simple example I could think of to make it relevant to all. Obviously this was not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and `.splice()` to get the expected result.
If `array2` is not allowed to be changed, we need a copy of it -> `.slice()`

```js
const array1 = [["John", "Barry", "Anne"], ["Greg"], ["Tom"], ["Roy", "Rye"]];
const array2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Pineapple", "Raspberry","Pear"];

// if array2 can be modified, then this is not necessary
// and you have to replace <clone> with <array2> in the block below
const clone = array2.slice(); 

const newArray = array1.map(inner => {
    return clone.splice(0, inner.length);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

---

*Answer for the first version of the question*

You only need `.map()` (twice) and a little bit of math for this.

```js
const array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4],
  [5],
  [6, 7]
];
const array2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Pineapple", "Raspberry", "Pear"];

const newArray = array1.map(inner => {
  return inner.map(n => {
    return array2[n - 1];
  })
});

console.log(newArray);
```

(can be written as a one-liner but for easier readability I've used an explicit `return`)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sorry for not saying in my original post this but array1 won't always be ordered numbers. How would your solution change if array1 was text?

Comment: Then add it in your question, and update the example. _"How would your solution change if array1 was text?"_ - I have no idea what this means... The elements in `array1` are not numbers but strings (`["1", "2", ...]`). If so, then just parse them (`n` in case of my answer) into actual numbers. You will find plenty of solutions here on SO or Google/Bing/Yahoo ;)

Comment: I've edited the my question. Sorry if I wasn't clear, the elements within array1 may be strings that can't be parsed to numbers. I would prefer a solution that does not rely on using array1 elements as an index reference.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const array1 = [["John", "Barry", "Anne"], ["Greg"], ["Tom"], ["Roy", "Rye"]];
const array2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Pineapple", "Raspberry","Pear"];

let indexTracker=0;

const newArr = array1.map(nameArr => nameArr.map(_ => array2[indexTracker++]));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map()` and `Array.slice()` to get the final result.

```js
const array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [6, 7]]
const array2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Pineapple", "Raspberry", "Pear"]

let index = 0;
const finalArray = array1.map((itemList) => {
  const list = array2.slice(index, index + itemList.length);
  index += itemList.length;
  return list;
});

console.log(finalArray);
```